# Creating MySQL stored procedures using MySQL

Tags: mysql, metaprogramming

Is there a way to programmatically create stored procedures using MySQL?  I can write a stored procedure to create databases and tables using prepared statements, but I get an error message saying it is not supported to create stored procedures with prepared statements.

I realize I can do this in PHP or Java, but so far I have been keeping all my schema management tools as SQL scripts, and I would like to avoid a second language dependency if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method you can try is to build the `create procedure` statement dynamically in SQL, then use `select into outfile` to dump the statement to local disk, and then source the file to load the procedure into the DB.

Here's a quick example:

```
set @proc_name = 'my_proc';
set @body1 = 'select ''hello''; ';
set @body2 = 'select ''world''; ';
set @delimiter = '$$';

set @create_proc_stmt = concat(
  'create procedure ',
  @proc_name,
  '() begin ', 
  @body1,
  @body2, 
  ' end ',
  @delimiter
);

select @create_proc_stmt into outfile '/tmp/create_proc_stmt.sql';

delimiter $$
\. /tmp/create_proc_stmt.sql
delimiter ;

call my_proc();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by inserting a record into `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` table. I haven't tried it, but it should work (one day in the past I forgot to add --routines switch to mysqldump, and later I restored all procedures by dumping this one table).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately it seems that INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a read only table:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html